# Wireless Internet is "Unidentified"?

Tags: connection, ipv6, ipv4, wireless-adapter

My laptop wireless refuses to connect with my wireless adapter. It says signals all good and ip address is cool, but my ipv4 ad ipv6 connectivity is "no netwok access". What do i do with that?

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure that you typed in the password correctly. Also, make sure that if you don't know how to set up a connection manually, make sure that the router is broadcasting the SSID. If it isn't, allow it to broadcast the SSID so that you can connect to it more "user friendly."

Answer (score 1):

check the followings:

- is the wireless adapter configured with static ip address or DHCP? if it's static ip address change it to DHCP; if you insist on static IP then check if your default gateway is correct.
- login to your router, can you do so? then check whether the WAN is connected

to further trouble shoot, please indicate

- if other machines can connect to the wifi router & go onto the internet
- whether machines connected to the wired network can go onto the internet
- post output of `ipconfig` and `route print -4`